# Cant Start Hostapd because multiple Errors

Tags: linux, debian, configuration, error-handling, hostapd

I have multiple errors while trying to start Hostapd
I will post the errors output which i got after i tried to start it and looked at the status:

```
   root@l0calh0st:~# service hostapd status
● hostapd.service - Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-01-07 16:42:38 CET; 4s ago
  Process: 1682 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=exited, sta

Jan 07 16:42:38 l0calh0st systemd[1]: Starting Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticato
Jan 07 16:42:38 l0calh0st hostapd[1682]: Configuration file:
Jan 07 16:42:38 l0calh0st hostapd[1682]: Could not open configuration file '' for reading.
Jan 07 16:42:38 l0calh0st hostapd[1682]: Failed to set up interface with
Jan 07 16:42:38 l0calh0st hostapd[1682]: Failed to initialize interface
Jan 07 16:42:38 l0calh0st systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 07 16:42:38 l0calh0st systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 07 16:42:38 l0calh0st systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authe
```

I dont know why he dont find the configuration file he seems to search for ' ' aka nothing...! I don't edited anything....! Here if i try to start it normal:

```
root@l0calh0st:~# service  hostapd start
Job for hostapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status hostapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

If use the command "journalct1 -xe" i get:

```
root@l0calh0st:~# journalctl -xe
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Jan 07 16:57:44 l0calh0st systemd[1]: Starting Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator...
-- Subject: Unit hostapd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit hostapd.service has begun starting up.
Jan 07 16:57:44 l0calh0st hostapd[1865]: Configuration file:
Jan 07 16:57:44 l0calh0st hostapd[1865]: Could not open configuration file '' for reading.
Jan 07 16:57:44 l0calh0st hostapd[1865]: Failed to set up interface with
Jan 07 16:57:44 l0calh0st hostapd[1865]: Failed to initialize interface
Jan 07 16:57:44 l0calh0st systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 07 16:57:44 l0calh0st systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 07 16:57:44 l0calh0st systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
-- Subject: Unit hostapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd 
-- Unit hostapd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
lines 1521-1543/1543 (END)
```

Edit: Ok, i found the file "hostapd.service" but i don't see anything commented-out. (#?):

```
[Unit]
Description=Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/hostapd.pid
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/hostapd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the /etc/default/hostapd file:

```
# Defaults for hostapd initscript
#
# See /usr/share/doc/hostapd/README.Debian for information about alternative
# methods of managing hostapd.
#
# Uncomment and set DAEMON_CONF to the absolute path of a hostapd configuration
# file and hostapd will be started during system boot. An example configuration
# file can be found at /usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf.gz
#
#DAEMON_CONF=""

# Additional daemon options to be appended to hostapd command:-
#   -d   show more debug messages (-dd for even more)
#   -K   include key data in debug messages
#   -t   include timestamps in some debug messages
#
# Note that -B (daemon mode) and -P (pidfile) options are automatically
# configured by the init.d script and must not be added to DAEMON_OPTS.
#
#DAEMON_OPTS=""
```

Comment: Launch hostpad by hand to see the errors. In your question, you also fail to explain what changes you made to arrive to this state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't edited anything...! And i don't understand  what do you mean "by Hand"?

Comment: I am not familiar with hostapd but it looks like you're supposed to uncomment the DAEMON_CONF="" line and populate it with the path of your config file. Something like DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/default.conf" If you read right above the line with the commented DAEMON_CONF you can see the path to an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your system is using `systemd`. In some distributions, I've noticed that using the legacy `service` wrapper can hide some error messages that would be visible using the systemd-native `systemctl` command. But it looks like there is enough information here.

In `/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service` file, the line that determines the actual command used to start `hostapd` is apparently this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF}
```

Since it includes environment variables that are outside `systemd`'s default set (see `man systemd.exec` for details), the `hostapd.service` file should probably have an option like `Environment=`, `EnvironmentFile=` or `PassEnvironment=`. Probably something like:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/hostapd.conf
```

If such a file exists, it probably has some commented-out defaults you'll need to edit to match your system configuration and then uncomment, before you can start `hostapd`.

Usually such files are prepared by your distribution maintainers, and have helpful comments describing what you'll need to do. If not, there might be some distribution-specific information in `/usr/share/doc/hostapd-*/` directory which you should read first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited my post because i found the file but don't see anything commented-out. ( # )

Comment: Are the DAEMON_OPTS and DAEMON_CONF environment variables defined in the `/etc/default/hostapd` file? What are their values?

Comment: mhhh i found the file, and copied it in my post. I think the variables are defined there but i dont understand what to do?

Comment: Now it's just a matter of following the instructions in it: get the example configuration file and copy it to somewhere e.g. `zcat /usr/share/doc/hostapd/examples/hostapd.conf.gz | sudo tee /etc/hostapd.conf`, then edit `/etc/hostapd.conf` to suit your requirements, uncomment and edit the DAEMON_CONF variable in `/etc/default/hostapd` to point to `/etc/hostapd.conf` and you should be ready to start hostapd.

Comment: Thank you!!!  The Error with the configuration file is now away..! But i still get the Errors with  "systemd[1]" in front of them and the "(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)" but i will look if this disapeares after I edited the configuration file.

Comment: Ok, everything is working now!!! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as you on Raspbian Stretch. I just search on [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=hostapd) and I found two different packages.
I installed **"hostapd_2.4-1+deb9u4_armhf.deb"** and it had plenty of problem. So, I installed **"hostapd_2.7+git20190128+0c1e29f-4_bpo9+2_armhf.deb"** and it was good.